# Extraneous entry in bibliography (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

here an image of my bibliography.

[image]

As per the image, LaTeX makes an extra entry in my bibliography. Note that I do not have this references in my `references.bib`, nor do I have any references labelled [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51HAf.png) in the text itself.

Here's my preamble, if it helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\settimeformat{hhmmsstime}
\doublespacing
\raggedbottom
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ackname{Acknowledgements}
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \ackname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{acknowledgements}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \ackname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5\textwidth}}

\newcommand{\latex}{\LaTeX\xspace}
\newcommand{\tex}{\TeX\xspace}

\lstset{
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\small, 
numbersep=8pt, 
frame = single, 
language=R, 
framexleftmargin=15pt}
```

Here's an example of an entry in my `references.bib`

```
@online{QuickR,
author = {Robert I. Kabacoff},
title = {About Quick-R},
year = {2012},
url = {http://www.statmethods.net/},
}


@online{StackOverflow,
author = {Stack Exchange Inc},
title = {Welcome to Stack Overflow},
year = {2014},
url = {http://stackoverflow.com/about},
}
```

Edit: file can be found here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/52da502aa5d18bc436000021

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Whats in your references.bib?

Comment: @Chris added an example.

Comment: Your example doesn't help to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Alright, I have made the entire document public.

Comment: and the bibliography?? With your demo bib you'll get no problem.

Comment: @WetFeet An obvious error to correct is that you miss a trailing comma at line 44 of `references.bib`. I'd also change all “curly apostrophes” `‘` into `'` in the `.bib` file. Finally, it could be a version problem: ShareLaTeX uses `biblatex` version 1.7, which is quite outdated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an input error that was fixed in the comments.